# Looking for the closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\zeta(2n+1)\over (2n+1)2^{4n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, closed-form, zeta-functions

We was able to determine $(1)$ to have this closed form

$$\ln(2)-\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\zeta(2n+1)\over (2n+1)2^{2n}}\tag1$$

then we when on and try to evaluate $(2)$ and we only half of the closed form

$$2\ln(2)-\gamma-2X=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\zeta(2n+1)\over (2n+1)2^{4n}}\tag2$$

Where $$X=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\eta(2n+1)\over(2n+1)2^{2n+1}}\tag3$$

where $\eta$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) and $\gamma$ is [Euler-Masheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

**How do we evaluate the closed form of $(3)?$**

Comment: I am not sure, but have you tried the identity $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2n+1)}{2n+1} z^{2n+1} = -\gamma z + \frac{\log\Gamma(1-z) - \log\Gamma(1+z)}{2}$$?

Comment: No I haven't @Sangchu Lee

Comment: Hint: The generating funtion of Riemann-Zeta is given by $\gamma+\psi(1+x)=-\sum_{n\geq1}\zeta(n+1)(-x)^n$

Comment: going all the way through the algebra we obtain $-\gamma+2\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}\right)$ i think

Comment: Thank @tired. I was checking on the sum calculator the numerical value seem correct.

Comment: By any chance you could present all the algebra that give the result, please. Thank you.

Comment: Done! :-). I tried to be as self contained as possible

Comment: @SangchulLee as usual you are right, see my answer below :-)

Comment: @tired, Thank you :) I know that the identity is true, but was not sure if OP was ever aware of this kind of computation. As I have been busy to sit at the computer today, I'm glad that you took this chore and wrote down a full answer. Of course (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the following Lemma (a sketch of a proof can be found below)

$$
s(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-x)^n \zeta(n+1)=-\gamma-\psi(1+x)\quad \color{red}{(I)}
$$

where $\psi(z)=\frac{d\log(\Gamma(z))}{dz}$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant

---

Integrating yields

$$
S(x)=\int dx s(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\zeta(n+1)}{n+1}(-x)^{n+1}=-\gamma x-\log(\Gamma(1+x))
$$

Taking the odd part
$$
S(x)-S(-x)=2\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\zeta(2n+1)}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=-2\gamma x-\log(\Gamma(1+x))+\log(\Gamma(1-x))
$$

Now let us put $x=\frac{1}{4}$ we get

> $$
> \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\zeta(2n+1)}{2n+1}\frac1{4^{2n}}=-\gamma+2\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}\right)
> $$

which is the sum of OP's interest

---

We now proof $\color{red}{(I)}$:

Use the definition of the $\zeta$-function as a series and exchange the order of summation. Doing the first sum yields $S(x)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{x+k}-\frac{1}k$ [expressing this in terms of Digamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) yields $\color{red}{(I)}$.

QED

Comment: I believe you meant to let $x=1/2$?